# Setting an external startpage with Cordova 1.6 on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, external

is it possible to load an external index.html (with included cordova.js) instead of the local one?

i found in the appdelegate.m this code:

```
self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";
```

i tried to reference an external url but without luck... anyone know a solution for this?

p.s.

with android it's easy:

```
super.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.135:3000/");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done this for my project (AppDelegate.m):

```
self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES; // YES;
self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @""; // @"www";
self.viewController.startPage = @""; // @"index.html";
self.viewController.invokeString = invokeString;
self.viewController.view.frame = viewBounds;

// Load request with new root URL
NSURL *urlOverwrite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://kyryll.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlOverwrite];

[self.viewController.webView loadRequest:request];
```

As mentioned elsewhere, the site you are trying access has to be whitelisted.

It's working nicely. My external site is on local IIS and has the cordova.js as well as few plugins. Now just have to see if I get Apple to approve my app!

Comment: I am trying too , to have an external url on the start of my app. I wasnt sure though how i would load the plugins for push notifications for example. so i should have them externaly loaded to the url too?

Answer (score 2):

If you [include the PhoneGap source as a subproject](http://mobiledan.net/2012/05/02/compile-phonegap-source-code-in-your-ios-phonegap-project/) (I used 1.7 and the directions still worked, see my note at the end), you can add a few lines of code to allow PhoneGap to support external URLs as the `startPage`.

Around line 133, you'll want to add

```
if([self.startPage hasPrefix:@"http"]) {
    appURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.startPage];
}
else
```

right before `if (startFilePath == nil) {`

By default, PhoneGap doesn't seem to support external startPage URLs without a javascript 'hack' mentioned above.  Other than this (and that), I know no other way!

Let me know if you have more questions.

Note:  as I mentioned above, the walkthrough is missing one step.  I commented on the article to let the author know, but it hasn't been approved yet.  Below is my comment:

> A step that was missing for me was adding $(CORDOVALIB)/Classes to the Header Search Path under Build Phases (also marking it to recursively search). Other than that, great write up!

Answer (score 2):

For iOS it would be:

```
self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @""; // @"www"
self.viewController.startPage = @"http://192.168.2.107:9000/";
```

The names are confusing because the startPage is also the URL.

Comment: I've reformatted your code but try and do so properly in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I did is, include following script block in an index.html file and remove other code if not required:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.location.href="http://192.168.1.135:3000/";
</script>
```

And include the host in the `ExternalHosts` map in `PhoneGap.plist` file, also check `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView` is set to `YES` in plist file

Comment: thanks, it's working! but it's not the way it's done on android. is there a better way?

Comment: although i don't know the exact reason but phonegap uses the native controls to create the required container in which case android might be supporting that but the iOS container might not be. Also if you look carefully in case of android we give absolute url to load the local resource whereas in iOS we set folder name and file name separately.

Comment: yes, you're right. i'm not sure, but i think it was possible with phonegap 1.4. now you have to specify a folder and file -.-

Answer (score 0):

Setting the wwwFolderName to empty string did not work for me but nil worked.

```
self.viewController.wwwFolderName = nil;
self.viewController.startPage = @"http://192.168.2.107:9000/";
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I did is, xxxViewController: CDVViewController<...>

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    self.wwwFolderName = @"dist";
    self.startPage = @"test.html";
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

so,that is all.