# Using PhoneGap/Cordova on iOS with external URL

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, apple-push-notifications

I want my phonegap/cordova app to load an external page and nothing local.

Now that i do that , however my plugins (javascript) dont work because they are called from the local index.html.

What do i do in this case? I should put the plugins on my external URL and load them on the external index.html? Also i should also load there the cordova-2.5.0.js ?

And if this is the only way , what happens if i want to load an external page that i dont own the server , but i would like to have push notifications enabled?

How would i enable those plugins?

Comment: i tried this ,but device ready is not called at any cost.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

***d0nparalias***,

Look at this project: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/930742/so/CordovaBrowserSO.zip

As you can see there is no `index.html` or `www/` folder inside.

All files were uploaded to the server and app will download them as needed.

I've accomplished it by doing steps from p.1. from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15319156/753878 answer.

At the server I have all files that you can see in basic `www/` folder created with template Cordova project:
[image: Server contents]

All plugins & stuff you include directly in `index.html` on your server.

If you check `config.xml` from the archive above you'll see
`<content src="http://dymv.comeze.com/www/index.html" />`

And the app on launch will say:
[image: Launching sample app]

Hope it's what you want to reach.
If it's not — please provide more info about result you want to achieve.

BR.
Eugene

Comment: Another great answer. This was exactly what i needed. So to sum up , whatever plugin i want/need to use , i put all the javascript on the server side and just include it on my external index.html? I tried the pushnotifications plugin , i put in my app all the native code and included my javascript on my external url on my server and everything works perfectly. But i have one question. When i was trying manually to delete the www folder from my project , when i started xcode i was getting an error about the folder missing. So in the end i used your xcode project.how did u do it without error?

Comment: Also can you please tell me whats the procedure on making the application loading an external url on the phonegap 2.1 , where theres no config.xml , but a .plist ?

Comment: >So in the end i used your xcode project.how did u do it without error?//// You should delete script in Build Phases which copies www folder to the Bundle I guess.

Comment: Yes you are right! Now works perfectly! How can i do this : <content src="http://dymv.comeze.com/www/index.html" />  , in the phonegap-2.1.0 that has a .plist instead of a config.xml?

Comment: Also can you please tell me whats the procedure on making the application loading an external url on the phonegap 2.1 , where theres no config.xml , but a .plist ?//// Actually I suggest you to upgrade Cordova if there is any possibilities to do that. Now I'm inspecting your question about version 2.1. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/12504248/753878 could be helpful? But I had no luck with it.

Comment: i need to support ios 4.3. Do u have any idea whats the latest cordova version supporting it? Thats why i tried 2.1.0 which for sure does

Comment: d0nparalias, First of all you can use version 2.2.0 to support 4.3, since 2.3.0 4.3 support was dropped. Secondly, I made it, kinda hack but it works. Key changes(commits) are 66045c and 5cf922. See git diff for more info inside project folder. Here project https://dl.dropbox.com/u/930742/so/OldCordova22.zip Cheers

Comment: "Key changes(commits) are 66045c and 5cf922. See git diff for more info inside project folder" I dont understand what you are saying. How can i see what code you changed? Its just an xcode project working , but what did you change?

Comment: Run git log -u -1 66045c inside project folder like this http://dl.dropbox.com/u/930742/Screenshots/ce4_.png Try for another commit, see all commits by git log

Comment: And of course you can do it from Xcode. Just go Organizer -> Repositories -> OldCordova22 and you'll see all my commits

Comment: i see you do "if (startFilePath == nil && NO)" . You could also let it like "if (startFilePath == nil)" and on the appdelegate put @"" where the wwwFolderName and startPage are. This just for future reference. Thanks a lot man !!! Works great :)

Comment: Hey @dymv. I wanted to ask you , if you ever tried submitting an app like the one we described above , where we load the "www" folder externally. The reason i am asking is because i just read on Apple that "Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected". In the our scenario all the code is external (html , css , javascript) and could change at any time. So i guess this is smth you are not supposed to do?

Comment: i tried the same method ,i was able to load the www folder from the server side.But the deviceready is not listened at any cost.Hope you might help

Comment: Can u share the project including the html pages.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Project: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/930742/so/CordovaBrowserSO.zip HtmlPages: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/930742/so/CordovaBrowserSO-WWW.zip Please create more detailed question rather than comment under my answer.

Comment: Found this after some searching. I'm running into a similar problem (close to 6 months after the latest post on this). Has anyone tried/gotten this to work with latest versions of cordova (3.+)?

Comment: Follow-up (Added for others who find this question): Works with 3.1 but you need to also move the cordova-plugins.xml file to the remote server as well. Still not sure what Apple's policy of doing something like this would be.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.loadURL = function(url){
    navigator.app.loadUrl(url, { openExternal:true });
    return false;
}
```

to use it in a tag eg

```
<a href='#' onclick="window.loadUrl('http://google.com'); return false;">open</a>
```